# drbl : virtual machine node fals to infinite boot loop

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, infinite-loop, boot, drbd

I run Debian linux. 
I want to make a virtual machine in virtualbox, wich boots from a server via drbl.
The server will be my laptop.

The virtual machine start booting, but fall into infifite boot-loop.
It load one part of the OS from the server, then stop loading, start it again...

Have anyone seen this error?